# Не срабатывает UPDATE поля

Tags: mysql

Доброго всем здравия.

Вопрос с SQL, вот такой код и почему-то не вносит изменения в БД.

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $userstable SET $userstable.Ostatok='$OST1', $userstable.Reserve='$REZ1' WHERE $userstable.Sklad_ID='T0001' and $userstable.ItemID='$ID'", $db);
print("<br>остаток T0001:".$OST1." резерв:".$REZ1." skladID:".$skldID." ID товара:".$ID."<br>");
```

Поля обновляемые формата DOUBLE. Почему вроде бы очевидно-правильный запрос не UPDATE'ит эти поля?

Comment: Тут дело не в запросе...скорее всего, не было установлено соединение с сервером БД.

Comment: Вижу имена таблиц и строк заданы как переменные, а этим переменным заданы таблицы и строки ???

Comment: @Asen
не было установлено соединение? О_о!
Это что-то из:
| - У меня не работает телевизор.
| - А вы в розетку его включали?
| - Да!
| - Хм...,
| - А то, что у меня отключили свет, от этого может не работать?
| - O_o!!!!!!

Comment: @Berserk
Мысль вашу понял, попробую. Но на функционал это ведь всё равно не повлияет.

Comment: @I_CaR А зачем вообще имена таблиц заменять переменными, почему не проще просто вписывать в запрос имя таблицы или просто имя строки ?

Comment: Почему не так

    UPDATE `userstable` SET userstable.Ostatok='".$OST1."', userstable.Reserve='".$REZ1."' WHERE userstable.Sklad_ID="T0001" and userstable.ItemID='".$ID."'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, но именно это сработало!

```
//ЭТО работает!!!
$result3 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $userstable3 SET $userstable3.Ostatok='$OST2' WHERE $userstable3.Sklad_ID='$skldID' and $userstable3.ItemID='$ID'", $db);
```

Выполняется даже 3 секунды, работа SQL очевидна

А это:

```
$result3 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $userstable3 SET $userstable3.Ostatok=".$OST2." WHERE $userstable3.Sklad_ID=".$skldID." and $userstable3.ItemID=".$ID."", $db);
```

Выполняется примерно 0,0249 сек. и ни каких изменений в БД.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - опять кавычки(

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $userstable SET $userstable.Ostatok='".$OST1."', $userstable.Reserve='".$REZ1."' WHERE $userstable.Sklad_ID='T0001' and $userstable.ItemID='".$ID."'", $db);
```

И перед выполнением запроса проверьте - содержатся ли данные в переменных, участвующих в запросе.

Comment: print("<br>остаток T0001:".$OST1."....
Этим принтом и проверяю ведь, всё есть.
Ок, попробую Ваш вариант, хотя предыдущий запрос на др. таблицу срабатывает именно с моим вариантом кавычек.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result2 = mysql_query ("UPDATE $userstable SET $userstable.Ostatok='$OST1', $userstable.Reserve='$REZ1' WHERE $userstable.Sklad_ID='T0001' and $userstable.ItemID='$ID'", $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

**И тогда, даже я бы сказал и Только ТОГДА! Наши пытливые умы смогут понять причину ошибки!**